# Check for Value for a Key in Dict within Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to run a Ansible Task in a string(`vlan`) is found within a keys (`name`) value. i.e

**dict**

```
interfaces_l3:
  - name: vlan101
    ipv4: 192.168.1.100/24
    state: present
```

**task**

```
- name: Enable Features
  nxos_feature:
     feature: interface-vlan
     state: enabled
  when: vlan in interfaces_l3.values()
```

This is what I have but currently, this is not working.

Comment: It's always helpful to show the actual error message, rather than just stating that it's "not working". In this case the problems were fairly obvious, but sometimes the error messages are quite helpful in determining the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your expression:

1. `interfaces_l3.values()` should just blow up, because `interfaces_l3` is a **list**, and lists don't have a `.values()` method.
2. You are referring to a variable named `vlan` rather than a string `"vlan"`.

You are asking if any item in the `interfaces_l3` list contains the string `"vlan"` in the value of the `name` attribute.  You could do something like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    interfaces_l3_with_vlan:
      - name: vlan101
        ipv4: 192.168.1.100/24
        state: present

    interfaces_l3_without_vlan:
      - name: something else
        ipv4: 192.168.1.100/24
        state: present

  tasks:
    - name: this should run
      debug:
        msg: "enabling features"
      when: "interfaces_l3_with_vlan|selectattr('name', 'match', 'vlan')|list"

    - name: this should be skipped
      debug:
        msg: "enabling features"
      when: "interfaces_l3_without_vlan|selectattr('name', 'match', 'vlan')|list"
```

Which produces the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [this should run] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "enabling features"
}

TASK [this should be skipped] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```